# Is it possible to revive a priest in Orctown?

Tags: nethack

In the new version of nethack, there is something called Orctown, which is a version of Minetown overrun by orcs, its normal inhabitants slaughtered.

I can't help but notice that there appears to be a priest corpse (more precisely there is a corpse right where the priest should be, I'm not sure it's not a watchman) right in the remains of the temple.

My questions:

- Is this actually a priest corpse?
- What alignment will he be if I revive him?
- Would the temple still be considered a temple?
- How will the watchman act if I revive him?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ The Orcish Town was added to Nethack 3.6.0 & UnNetHack.

Answer (score 3):

So I fired up a wizardmode (debug) game and tested this scenerio.
Didn't do exactly what I expected.

So hacked and slashed my way through the orcs. Blessed wand of locking does NOT create locked doors at the gap leading into the temple, you have to use a blessed (or uncursed) scroll of earth.

Wished for a white unicorn corpse (I was a chaotic wizard) changed the altar to chaotic (from moloch) then zapped the priest corpse with a wand of undead turning.

Surprise! The corpse turned into a human zombie.

I then wished for an uncursed priest corpse (in case it had been sitting too long) the wand of undead turning revived the priest corpse into a Hostile Adept.

Comment: Can you turn this from a story into a proper answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

Much of the fun in Nethack is exploring options, but it seems you want to be spoiled.  Unfortunately, I can't find some of the details of this question explicitly spoiled online, and I for one, don't feel like code diving, so ...

### Let's Examine what is known (publicly spoiled):

- The [Altar in the Orcish Town is known to be Unaligned, and the corpse in question is indeed a Priest](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Mine_town#Orcish_Town).  It's not identified as a `high altar` so let's assume it can be converted.
- An Orcish character has a decent chance of being ignored by the residents of the Orcish Town.
- Corpses rot & disappear over time.  So you'll need to do the deed shortly after generating the level for the 1st time.  This may be difficult for someone who chooses to explore the mine town before visiting the Oracle unless they are an Orc.
- Corpses can be revived with either a `wand of undead turning` or `The Book of the Dead`.  Owners of The Book probably don't care much about the mine town any more and have likely visited the town so long ago that the corpse is a distant memory.
- Attendant Priests in Temples no longer dedicated to their own alignment generally throw "tantrums".
- Free roaming Priests who are not restricted to a Temple are generally friendly even if they are in the vicinity of a cross-aligned altar, but are generally useless for chatting.
- <s>If you're playing an Orc, converting the altar to Chaotic should be relatively easy with all of the available orc corpses.  Just food for thought. "[Looks like meat's back on the menu, boys!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dY4V3UUY95A)"</s> Oops!  Looking at the Orc Town entry, *this* altar is not a candidate for conversion by same-race sacrifice.

### What results can we reasonably expect?

Presuming we get to the Orcish Town for the 1st time with a `wand of undead turning` and strong enough (or orcish enough) to survive the orcs on the way to the corpse in question (and convert the altar?), all before the corpse rots away, we could get one of a couple results depending on how the Dev Team coded the game:

- A useless free roaming Priest.  At very best he might be grateful to be alive again and becomes "tame". - I have my suspicions that this is the true answer.  Much effort for little, if any, reward.
- A passionate Temple Priest.  Does he wake dedicated to Law? Chaos? Neutrality? Moloch?  Is the altar still Moloch's or did you convert it to your alignment?  Can you survive the possibility of a priest tantrum caused by a mismatch? - I don't expect this is the way the game has been coded.  Altars dedicated to Molock are seldom a promise of "good things", but I've been surprised before.

Comment: This answer is just wrong.  The priest does not revive as a priest, but as a human zombie.  Wizmode wishing for a "priest corpse" doesn't work either, as that gives you a player monster corpse.  Try wishing for an "aligned priest corpse".

Comment: Also, even if you somehow manage to get a temple priest, he would never be tame or even peaceful. As soon as you step near him or #chat to him (maybe not the former, I don't remember), he will turn hostile again, since the temple is desecrated (which can't be reversed).